# Разработка нативных приложений на android и ios на javascript, как это работает?

Tags: node.js, react-native

Я знаком с такими фреймворками, как react и react native, 2-й позволяет создавать нативные приложения под разные мобильные платформы, но я совсем не понимаю как это работает, если возьмем например андроид и разработку на java, то в самом андроид есть виртуальная машина, которая понимает байт код и позволяет скомпилировать машинный код, в случая с javascript для меня немного непонятно как это работает, как js обрабатывается, что его начинает понимать платформа ?

Comment: JS остаётся JS, он никак дополнительно не обрабатывается.

Comment: @D-side, можете подробней обьяснить как тогда на платформе iOS и андроид происходит запуск нативных написанных на is приложений )

Comment: Выполнять код на JS можно только реализацией JS, в RN, емнип, используется JavaScriptCore. Он зашивается внутрь каждого приложения.

Comment: @D-side, тоесть jscore содержит в себе интерпретатор js  и за счёт этого приложение запускается на платформе ?

Comment: Он не содержит его, он им напрямую является :) а вот приложения на RN его уже содержат.

Comment: @D-side, большое спасибо ) тоесть по сути приложение с платформой взаимодействует только благодаря jscore ?)